# WPF UI to allow user scheduling

Tags: wpf, scheduler

I'd like to display a UI in my WPF app much like the 'Scheduled Tasks' UI in Windows.

I'm planning to suck out the parameters of the task from the UI and schedule it on a server.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel by doing all this myself though.

There's plenty of scheduler libraries out there (like Quartz) that run as a service and run tasks at preset times - but I need just a UI.

Answer (score 3):

Here's someone who's decided to roll their own, and provides the source code.

[WPF Scheduler control](http://www.oscardelossantos.es/en/developing/wpf-en-developing/wpf-scheduler-control-2/)

[image: WPF Scheduler control example]

Other vendors;

**DevExpress**

[image: WPF Scheduler Control example]

[WPF Scheduler Control](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/wpf/scheduler/)

**SyncFusion**

[image: SF WPF Scheduler example]

[WPF Scheduler](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/schedule)

**Mindfusion**

[image: Mindfusion WPF Planner example]

[WPF Planner](http://mindfusion.eu/wpfplanner.html)

**Mindscape**

[image: Mindscape WPF Scheduler]

[WPF Scheduler](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/wpfelements/controls/wpf-scheduler)

Answer (score 0):

Telerik has a Scheduler Control for WPF, there's a walk through article [here](http://blogs.telerik.com/johnkellar/posts/09-02-05/radscheduler_for_wpf_-_out_of_the_box.aspx)

Infragistics has a Scheduler Control for WPF as well, features [here](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf/schedule.aspx#Overview)